# How can I use templates to deduce the parameter types of a std::function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, std-function

I'm working on a problem to rotate an NxN matrix of type `T` by 90 degrees. In the spirit of DRY, I'd like the function signature of my rotate function to look like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void rotate_90(Matrix<T, N>& m, std::function<void(T&, T&, T&, T&)> swap_direction);
```

This will allow me to swap clockwise and counterclockwise with the same function simply by passing a different `std::function<void(T&, T&, T&, T&)>`.

I currently have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <functional>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<T, N>, N>;

template <typename T>
void four_way_swap_clockwise(T& top_left, T& top_right, T& bottom_left, T& bottom_right) {
    T temp = top_left;
    top_left = top_right;
    top_right = bottom_right;
    bottom_right = bottom_left;
    bottom_left = temp;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void rotate_90(Matrix<T, N>& m, std::function<void(T&, T&, T&, T&)> swap_direction) {
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < N/2; ++i) {
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < (N+1)/2; ++j) {
            swap_direction(
                m[i][j],
                m[N-j-1][i],
                m[j][N-i-1],
                m[N-i-1][N-j-1]
            );
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t N = 5;
    Matrix<int, N> m {{
        {{1,2,3,4,5}},
        {{6,7,8,9,10}},
        {{11,12,13,14,15}},
        {{16,17,18,19,20}},
        {{21,22,23,24,25}}
    }};

    std::function<void(int&, int&, int&, int&)> swap_clockwise(four_way_swap_clockwise);

    rotate_90(m, swap_clockwise);    
}
```

This currently doesn't compile, failing with the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::function<void(int&, int&, int&, int&)>::function(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
 std::function<void(int&, int&, int&, int&)> swap_clockwise(four_way_swap_clockwise);
```

However, even if it did compile, it also defeats the purpose of template programming to specify the type of the types of the parameters of the swap function (i.e., in the definition of `std::function<void(int&, int&, int&, int&)> swap_clockwise(four_way_swap_clockwise);`).

How can I pass the `std::function` with the template type deduced?

Comment: Any reason why you cannot simply use a single template type to represent the function?

Comment: @WhiZTiM If I understand what you mean, you're suggesting a globally scoped `std::function<void(T&, T&, T&, T&)>`. Is this correct? If so, that's definitely an option, but I wasn't sure how idiomatic/appropriate that is. I'm quite unfamiliar with `<functional>` and don't know the tricks yet. :)

Comment: @erip - not sure to undertand... whats wrong with `std::function<void(int&, int&, int&, int&)> swap_clockwise(four_way_swap_clockwise<int>);` ?

Comment: @max66 Oops, that was silly. While it now compiles, it doesn't address the _However_ bit of my question.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f20307fb3da42c9) what you had in mind? If so, I still need to specify the template type of the `std::function` being passed to `rotate_90`. Not sure if there's a way around this.

Comment: @erip - yes, It's a mad world, I suppose; but I don't understand exactly the *however* question. Please, could youd show how do you want to use your code?

Comment: @max66 basically I'd like the template type of the function to be automatically deduced as the same as the template type from the `Matrix`, but I'm starting to realize this might not be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class T> struct tag_t{using type=T;};
template<class T> using block_deduction=typename tag_t<T>::type;
```

This construct blocks C++ from trying to deduce template arguments from a function argument.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void rotate_90(Matrix<T, N>& m, block_deduction<std::function<void(T&, T&, T&, T&)>> swap_direction) {
```

now the type of the 2nd argument is always deduced from the type of the first!

The next problem is that `std::function` doesn't disambiguate overloaded function names.  An overloaded function name isn't a C++ value, it is a set of names which (in the right context) a value is found.  `std::function` construction is *not* one of those contexts.

We can extend `std::function` with an additional constructor like this:

```
template<class Sig, class F=std::function<Sig>>
struct my_func:F {
  using F::F;
  using F::operator=;
  my_func( Sig* ptr ):F(ptr) {}
  my_func& operator=( Sig* ptr ) {
    F::operator=(ptr);
    return *this;
  }
  my_func()=default;
  my_func(my_func&&)=default;
  my_func(my_func const&)=default;
  my_func& operator=(my_func&&)=default;
  my_func& operator=(my_func const&)=default;
};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c287fdf89fca0a46).

An alternative approach is to wrap your overload set into a lambda:

```
auto overloads = [](auto&&...args){ return four_way_swap_clockwise(decltype(args)(args)...); };
```

then pass the `overloads` to your function.  This lambda represents *all* over the overloads of `four_way_swap_clockwise` at once.

We can also manually disambiguate by doing `four_way_swap_clockwise<int>`.

Both of these still requires the `block_deduction` technique above.

An alternative to consider would be:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, class F>
void rotate_90(Matrix<T, N>& m, F&& swap_direction)
```

where we leave `swap_direction` completely free and let any failures occur within the algorithm.  This also gives a slight performance boost.  You still have to disambiguate the `four_way_swap_clockwise` with either `<int>` or the lambda-wrapper technique.

Another approach would be to make `for_way_swap_clockwise` a lambda itself:

```
auto four_way_swap_clockwise = [](auto& top_left, auto& top_right, auto& bottom_left, auto& bottom_right) {
  auto temp = top_left;
  top_left = top_right;
  top_right = bottom_right;
  bottom_right = bottom_left;
  bottom_left = temp;
};
```

and now it is an object with a template `operator()` overload.  This with `block_deduction` solves your problem.

In short, there are lots of ways around your problem.

Comment: There's a lot here to think about. Great answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

You may prefer to make `rotate_90` more generic like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename F>
void rotate_90(Matrix<T, N>& m, F swap_direction) {
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < N/2; ++i) {
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < (N+1)/2; ++j) {
            swap_direction(
                m[i][j],
                m[N-j-1][i],
                m[j][N-i-1],
                m[N-i-1][N-j-1]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would the usage be for this more generic version?

Comment: @erip : The exact same usage, except allowing for _any_ arbitrary callable with the appropriate signature instead of forcing use of `std::function<>` along with its inherent inefficiencies.

Answer (score 2):

To call the function,

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void rotate_90(Matrix<T, N>& m, std::function<void(T&, T&, T&, T&)> swap_direction);
```

given:

```
template <typename T>
void four_way_swap_clockwise(T& top_left, T& top_right, T& bottom_left, T& bottom_right);
```

you can simply try this:

```
rotate_90<int>(m, four_way_swap_clockwise<int>);
```

---

As to why you cannot call it like:

```
rotate_90(m, four_way_swap_clockwise);
```

It is partly because the name `four_way_swap_clockwise` is a *template-function* and **not** a *function*, and using such name requires its instantiation. which I instantiated as `four_way_swap_clockwise<int>`

Better still, as per my first comment on your Question, it will be better to write the `rotate_90` like:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename Func>
void rotate_90(Matrix<T, N>& m, Func swap_direction);
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I definitely overlooked that templates require instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

You could make your template function a functor:

```
struct four_way_swap_clockwise {
    template <typename T>
    void
    operator()(T& top_left, T& top_right, T& bottom_left, T& bottom_right) {
        T temp = top_left;
        top_left = top_right;
        top_right = bottom_right;
        bottom_right = bottom_left;
        bottom_left = temp;
    }
};
```

Then call:

```
four_way_swap_clockwise swap_clockwise;
rotate_90(m, swap_clockwise);
```

Comment: Wouldn't a template type need to be provided when initializing `swap_clockwise`?

Comment: No. You'd need to couple this what other posters have mentioned about making rotate_90 more generic.